# What is the meaning of a small o in between function names? i.e (f o g)

Tags: functions, notation

I am helping with homework.

I am stumped here - What is the meaning of the small round circle, or small "o" in question 19 (that I underlined) and question 20

[image: Camera shot of example]

Comment: @Ray,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition

Answer (score 12):

It is [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). If you have one function $f(x)$, and another function $g(x)$, then we can create a new function named  $g\circ f$ (read as: "$g$ composed with $f$") that is defined as
$$(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$$
For example, if $f(x)=x+1$, and $g(x)=2x-1$, then
$$(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=g(x+1)=2(x+1)-1=2x+1$$

Comment: Use of this symbol makes it possible to efficiently write things like $(g\circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$.

Comment: So does question 19 solve out to `16x^2 - 1`

Comment: @RajMore It goes like $h(4x+1) = (4x+1)^2-2 = 16x^2+8x+1-2 = 16x^2+8x-1$.

Comment: Doh me! It's slooooooooowly coming back to me